# Regex negative look behind does not work as intended, how do I make it work

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am not trying to accomplish anything except understand why this specific regex does not work as intended:

```js
/\bty(?!t)\b/i
```

Intended match:

- any string starting with 'ty' and not ending with 't'

From what I understood about negative lookbehind, it should match something not followed by something, and here i want to match tyX (X can be any character) as long as X is not 't'.

Should match:

```
tya
```

Should not match:

```
tyt
```

Using a negated set solves this easily, but I don't understand why a negative lookahead doesn't work.

Comment: That regex will match any *word* that starts with `ty` and does not end in `t`, case insensitive. This works for the negative case, `/\bty(?!t)\b/i.test('tyt')` yields false, but not the positive, `/\bty(?!t)\b/i.test('tya')` yields false as well.

Comment: Because your regex doesn't allow room for any other characters. Word boundary, two characters, nothing ahead with a `t`, but the only valid character after that for you is another word boundary. Try `\bty(?!t).*\b` . Also `?!` is a negative lookeahead, not behind.

Comment: Ahh thank u very much. i thought specifying ?!t would match anything not t

Comment: @AndyRay `\bty(?!t).*\b` will match a 4 or more letter string starting with `ty` and ending with `t`. https://regex101.com/r/ZDh1bg/1 Unclear if that's an issue or not for OP

Comment: @Nick wait how does that make 4 characters

Comment: plus, then is there a way to limit the length of the match? as in if the match is more than x chars it will not match? or is this functionality we need to implement with code

Comment: okay mb its 4 characters, the 2 \b and t,y

Comment: @Ethicist `.*` will match at least 0 characters. So `ty(?!t).*` will match anything starting with `ty` which doesn't have `t` as the third character. So it will match `ty`, `tya`, `tyat`, `tyaat` etc. See https://regex101.com/r/luZhdX/1

Comment: What is the length of the string that you want to match? If it should match "tya" and should not match "tyt", should there be 3 characters only? What should be the match in `tya#` or `tyt hello` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I understood about negative lookbehind, it should match something not followed by something, and here i want to match tyX (X can be any character) as long as X is not 't'.

- `(?!t)` is not a negative look *behind*, but a negative look *ahead*. You got that right further on in your question.
- `(?!t)` asserts that there is no `t` at this position, without moving the current position.
- `\bty(?!t)\b` cannot match `tyX`, as your regex requires a `\b` **immediately** after `ty`. There is no provision for a third character in this pattern.
- The ending `\b` asserts that the next character is not an alphanumerical, which already excludes "t", and so your regex is actually doing the same as `\bty\b` and so only the word `ty` can be matched (case insensitive).

To provide for longer words, you should add `\w*` after `ty`. To exclude words ending in a "t", you could use a negative look *behind* so to assert that the last character matched is not a "t":

```
\bty\w*(?<!t)\b
```

This will match all of the following:

```
ty
typ
type
typical
tyranny
typesetting
```

It will not match:

```
typeset
tyrant
typist
typescript
typologist
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved without using of negative look behind.

```
\bty(?:[a-z]*[a-su-z])?\b
```

The [regex](https://regex101.com/r/2WVfc7/3) can be broken down as follows.

```
\b         the boundary between a word char (\w) and
           something that is not a word char
-----------------------------------------------------
ty         'ty'
-----------------------------------------------------
(?:        group, but do not capture (optional
           (matching the most amount possible)):
-----------------------------------------------------
  [a-z]*     any character of: 'a' to 'z' (0 or more
             times (matching the most amount
             possible))
-----------------------------------------------------
  [a-su-z]   any character of: 'a' to 's', 'u' to 'z'
-----------------------------------------------------
)?         end of grouping
-----------------------------------------------------
\b         the boundary between a word char (\w) and
           something that is not a word char
```